# How to add message after submitting form? PHP, Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, submit, message

I trying to make a feature, where the user recieves a message saying "Your changes have been saved" after the user has pressed "save changes". When the form is being submittet the page is just refreshed and not redirected to any other page.

I have tried several things but nothing seems to work. I am good at HTML but not PHP. I would love if any of you could help me out!

My code for my profile template is the folowing:

```
<div class="user-image">            
<div class="bordered-image thick-border">
    <?php echo get_avatar(ThemexUser::$data['user']['ID'], 200); ?>
</div>
<div class="user-image-uploader">
    <form action="<?php echo themex_url(); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <label for="avatar" class="button"><span class="button-icon upload"></span><?php _e('Skift billede','academy'); ?></label>
        <input type="file" class="shifted" id="avatar" name="avatar" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_action" value="update_avatar" />
        <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce(THEMEX_PREFIX.'nonce'); ?>" />
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="user-description">

<form action="<?php echo themex_url(); ?>" class="formatted-form" method="POST">
    <div class="message">
        <?php ThemexInterface::renderMessages(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="sixcol column">
        <div class="field-wrapper">
            <input type="text" name="first_name" size="30" value="<?php echo ThemexUser::$data['user']['profile']['first_name']; ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Fornavn','academy'); ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sixcol column last">
        <div class="field-wrapper">
            <input type="text" name="last_name" size="30" value="<?php echo ThemexUser::$data['user']['profile']['last_name']; ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Efternavn','academy'); ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>              
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <!-- ADRESSE -->
    <?php if(!ThemexCore::checkOption('profile_signature')) { ?>
    <div class="field-wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="signature" value="<?php echo ThemexUser::$data['user']['profile']['signature']; ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Adresse','academy'); ?>" />
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="user-fields">
        <?php ThemexForm::renderData('profile', array(), ThemexUser::$data['user']['profile']); ?>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>

    <a href="#" class="button submit-button"><span class="button-icon save">    </span><?php _e('Gem ændringer','academy'); ?></a>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_action" value="update_profile" />
    <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce(THEMEX_PREFIX.'nonce'); ?>" />
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are submitting to another url. So you can add something like the below to your functions file to display a message when the url is appended with msg. (you can account for multiple messages using the switch below, look it up) also you will need to add `?msg=yourmessagevariable' to your form action.

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'notifcation', 100);

function notifcation () {

    if($_GET['msg']) {

        $message= sanitize_text_field($_GET['msg']);

        switch($message) {

            case 'reg-business':

                $notehead= 'Please register first';
                $msg= 'Please register your business before continuing';
                break;  

            case 'nowvalid':

                $notehead= "Congratulations";
                $msg='You have successfully connected ';
                break;

            case 'Completed':
                $notehead= 'Edited';
                $msg='You have successfully edited your advert';
                break;
        }


        ?>

            <section id="notification" class="notif notif-notice">
                  <h6 class="notif-title"><?php echo $notehead;?></h6>
                  <p><?php echo $msg; ?></p>

                  <div class="notif-controls">
                   <a href="index.html" class="notif-close">Close</a>
                   </div>
            </section>      

            <script type="text/javascript">

                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    jQuery('#notification').css('display', 'none');
                    },3000)

                });
                jQuery('.notif-close').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    jQuery(this).parent().parent().css('display', 'none');

                })

            </script>




        <?php

    }



}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer David! 
I am not how to add the "?msg=yourmessagevariable" correctly? Should it look something like this: <form action="<?php echo themex_url();?msg=Completed ?>">
Also I see two places with an <form action="">, which one should I add the code?
Lastly the notification.php file. What should that contain? I am not sure what you mean by "template for the note".
I am sorry if I may ask some stupid questions, but I really new at PHP..
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `<form action="<?php echo themex_url(); ?>?msg=Completed">` will do if there is not a ? already in there(i cant see the value of the THEMEX_URL). You have two forms on the page, you can use in both if you want, the first seems like a image submit and update avatar so maybe a different message there?

Comment: Thank you David! I will try is out and get back to you.

Comment: Okay so I put the code you made into my function.php. (Exact same code). I also put in <form action="<?php echo themex_url(); ?>?msg=Completed"> at each forms. (I also tried them separately) But still no success. Every time I try something new I check it by inspecting the site, just to make sure the text isn't hiding somewhere.

Comment: did you place the code in your functions.php file? also, did you create a template file for the output? (that is what require_once is looking for) if not just replace that line with `echo $message;` also i noticed a typo just after line i removed from the text above. Next thing to check is the format of your url, it should be like `www.yoursite.com/apage?msg='a message"` if fact if you type `?msg='message' after any url it should output the message.

Comment: Yes. The code is in my functions.php file.
Okay, so I replaced the requie_once with the "echo $message;". Now I get the URL (/profile/testuser?msg=Completed) as you predicted, but there is still no message showing.
You can test it out on our site here: www.reddernes.dk - User: testuser, pass: test1234

Comment: BTW. I really appreciate all your help David!

Comment: looks like the post hook is not called on that page, i've updated with a new hook to try.  To make the output more visible wrap it in <h1> tags but i'd recommend you set up a div for it. I've updated a sample one above as well.

Comment: Nice! So now the messages shows. But it shows in the upper left corner. How can I define where on the page it will show? Also, if I do a new save after the first one, the message chances to saying "close" and it links to /profile/index.html. So it shows the first time. Not the second.

Comment: Okay, so I just outcommented the part with the close. :) My last questions is: The first time I save, the message is shown. The second time I save, the message is not shown. And how can I define where on the page the message will pop up?

Comment: You need to do that with css. You can do something like `#notification{ position: fixed; top: 300px: left: 300px; }` and adjust it there to where-ever you want. The jQuery above you should place below your footer really and then it will work! Also you can replace the link with close in it for a image just give it the class `notif-close` and the close function will work.

Comment: Okay - We are almost there! I had it working with the close and so on. But it still only shows the "close" button the second time I save the changes. It shows the message perfectly the first time I save the changes.

Comment: When I save the second time, the URL looks like this: "/profile/testuser?msg=Completed?msg=Completed".

Comment: ok try in your form action `action="<?php get_site_url();?>/profile/testuser?msg=Completed"`

Comment: Cool! That fixed the problem. But >"testuser" is only one profilename. How do I make sure that it redirects back to the same user? I have tried the following without any luck. <form action="<?php get_site_url();?>/profile/<?php $current_user->user_login?>?msg=Completed">

Comment: try `action="<?php echo get_site_url().strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?');"`

Comment: If I use that an almost blank page is shown. The only thing that is showing is the header. The URL is "/profile/testuser".

Comment: This worked though: [action="<?php get_site_url();?>?msg=Completed">]  !!!  Thank you SO much David! I don't know how it works here on StackOverflow. Are there anyway I on this site can show my appreciation?

Comment: you're welcome, yes you can, show app by accepting the answer(green tick) and upvotes.

Comment: There we go! Sorry for the delay. :)